# ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware app.middleware: "cannot import name get_host"

Tags: django

I've just upgraded to Django 1.5, and when I try and access a page, I get the following error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware app.middleware: "cannot import name get_host"
```

In the shell, I try a similar thing:

```
>>> from app import middleware
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../middleware.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponsePermanentRedirect, get_host
ImportError: cannot import name get_host
```

It's failing on the import of `get_host`. It doesn't seem that this is deprecated, what's going on?

Comment: In [Django 1.5](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host) `django.http.get_host()` is replaced with `request.get_host()`

Comment: @AamirAdnan Thanks, post it as an answer so I can accept!

Comment: you are welcome. Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Django 1.5 `django.http.get_host()` is replaced with `request.get_host()`. See the methods on `HttpRequest` object [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host).