# Django Error while running server

Tags: django

getting error at localhost.
localhost: A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.

local_settings.py :
http://pastebin.com/JSFaBEg2

Error Log :
http://pastebin.com/ANrUvd9z

Comment: Did you read the error message? Did you try searching the web for it?

Comment: sure i m working through errors since morning removing one by one . being new to django i do google a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware` from the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` (it was deprecated in 1.4). You should use just `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` for cross-site request forgery protection.

See django's [deprecation timeline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/):

> 1.4
>
> CsrfResponseMiddleware and CsrfMiddleware will be removed. Use the {%
>   csrf_token %} template tag inside forms to enable CSRF protection.
>   CsrfViewMiddleware remains and is enabled by default.

Comment: now error changed : http://pastebin.com/hXnFqnXm

Comment: it's a custom middleware causing an error. Check if `get_host` is imported there.

Comment: SSLMiddleware.py : http://pastebin.com/HyRwTPJ8 . sry but i didn't get where get_host should have been imported

Comment: found : get_host is indeed imported there .

Comment: There is no `django.http.get_host` in django 1.5, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664951/improperlyconfigured-error-importing-middleware-app-middleware-cannot-import

Comment: yes i was looking at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.read it has get_host() method

Comment: on the request object, not in `django.http.get_host`. You should fix your middleware.

Comment: thanx got server running .

Comment: what's there in chat solved the problem not the main response please consider editing the answer accordingly .